# mysql count with aritmmetic operation with condition

Tags: mysql, math, conditional-statements

I have two tables.
job_table.

```
job_id  job_type    job_type       *****
1       1           Day            *****
2       2           Night
3       3           Day & Night.
4       3           Day & Night.
```

and task_entry table.

```
task_entry_id    job_type       task_option_type
1                1             Day
2                1             Day
3                1             Day
4                2             Night
5                3             Day  
6                3             Night
7                3             Day  
8                3             Night
```

If job id is 3 then there will be 2 entries one for Day and one for Night.
Else only one entry.

I want to get the total count of jobs with task_entries like this,

```
job_id      task_entry_count
1           3
2           1
3           2
```

That is if job_type is 3 then count should be count/2. (Day&Night).
Else count should be normal count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `JOIN` the two tables together and then use `GROUP BY` to get the number of total count of jobs.

```
SELECT jt.job_id,
    ROUND(SUM (CASE WHEN jt.job_type = 3 THEN 0.5 ELSE 1 END), 0) AS task_entry_count
FROM job_table jt INNER JOIN task_entry te
ON jt.job_type = te.job_type
GROUP BY jt.job_id
```

Comment: I think you missed the condition "If job_type is 3 then count should be count/2. (Day&Night). Else count should be normal count"

Comment: Yes. This solves my problem. But it returns count with decimal value as 1.0. I tried with CAST(SUM ( CASE WHEN jt.job_type = 3 THEN 0.5 ELSE 1 END)) AS INTEGER) AS task_entry_count. CAST is not working. How can get the integer count without decimal points in it.

Comment: How do you want to handle a case where a `SUM` has a value of, say, 3.5 ?  Should this be rounded to 4?  Or should it be truncated to 3?

Comment: I will not have that condition. Because if the job_type is 3 then there will be exact 2 records in table task_entry table. So the count will be always even number.

Comment: I updated my answer to `SUM` with twice the value, then divide by 2.  Please mark the answer correct if it worked.

Comment: Thats the same. I want to remove that decimal points. Right now i m getting the result as

3.0, 1.0 and 2.0

Comment: You should be able to use `ROUND` without worry since the totals are always whole numbers.